# R mapping slope and intercept from a table with linear models after facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

using the mtcars dataset, I used pivot_longer to get a long dataframe with the numeric variables.

```
mtcars_numeric <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, origin, mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec) 

mtcars_long_numeric <- pivot_longer(mtcars_numeric, names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 4:8)
```

I also now have created my own table. I've created different linear models and picked out the slope and intercept for different variables against mpg. Here is the table I created:

```
structure(list(terms = c("intercept", "intercept", "intercept", 
"intercept", "intercept", "slope", "slope", "slope", "slope", 
"slope"), names = c("wt", "disp", "drat", "hp", "qsec", "wt", 
"disp", "drat", "hp", "qsec"), values = c(37.2851, 29.59985, 
-7.525, 30.09886, -5.114, -5.3445, -0.04122, 7.678, -0.06823, 
1.412)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

I then split this new table I created into two: one table with information about the slope and one with information about the intercept. (Not sure if this is the best idea)

```
mapping_df_intercept <- mapping_df %>%
  filter(terms == "intercept")

mapping_df_slope <- mapping_df %>%
  filter(terms == "slope")
```

I'm now trying to get a graph with a unique geom_abline for each facet.

```
ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric, aes(x = values, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free') + 
  geom_abline(mapping = aes(intercept = values, data = mapping_df_intercept), aes(slope = values, data = mapping_df_slope), linetype = 'dashed')
```

This isn't working. Maybe geom_abline can't take two different aes sections.

If instead I try to use just one dataframe with both intercept and slope information and I try to put filtering into the argument, I can't get that to work either.

```
ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric, aes(x = values, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free') + 
  geom_abline(mapping = aes(intercept = mapping_df$values[mapping_df$terms == "intercept"], slope = mapping_df$values[mapping_df$terms == "slope"]), data = mapping_df, linetype = 'dashed')
```

I understand that I can just use geom_smooth and it's more simple but I'm trying something else just to practice this geom_abline mapping situation.

```
ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric, aes(x = values, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free') + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main struggle is trying to do this with a `mapping_df` that is longer than is convenient for this purpose. It becomes easier if the `aes()` parameters are columns in that data.

```r
mapping_df2 <- mapping_df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = terms, values_from = values)

ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric, aes(x = values, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(
    data = mapping_df2,
    aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ names, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Code below was run before code at the top, but doesn't address the question. Appending this for reproducibility reasons.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

mtcars_numeric <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>%
  dplyr::select(mpg, wt, disp, drat, hp, qsec) 

mtcars_long_numeric <- pivot_longer(mtcars_numeric, names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 2:6)

mapping_df <- structure(list(
  terms = c("intercept", "intercept", "intercept", 
            "intercept", "intercept", "slope", "slope", "slope", "slope", 
            "slope"), 
  names = c("wt", "disp", "drat", "hp", "qsec", "wt", 
            "disp", "drat", "hp", "qsec"), 
  values = c(37.2851, 29.59985, 
             -7.525, 30.09886, -5.114, -5.3445, -0.04122, 7.678, -0.06823, 
             1.412)
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```